# PHP fopen() invalid argument

Tags: php, fopen

I'm running this code once the user submits a form. The idea is to save a new file called "message_timestamp" where timestamp is the current date and time. It need to be saved in the misc folder, which is located in the same directory as this php file.

My code:

```
 if (isset($_POST['submitIssue'])) {

     $type = $_POST['typeOfIssue'];
     $prefName = $_POST['preferredName'];
     $email = $_POST['userEmail'];
     $details = $_POST['detailedReport'];
     date_default_timezone_set('Atlantic/Bermuda');
     $date = new DateTime('now');
     $date = $date->format('Y-m-d_H:i:s');
     $date = trim($date);
     $fileName = "misc/message_" . $date;
     $out = "Issue Alert!\nType of issue: " . $type . "\n\nSubmitted by " . $prefName . "\nEmail ID: " . $email . "\nSubmitted at: " . $date . "\n\nDetails: " . $details;

     $myFile = fopen($fileName,"w") or die("Cannot open file!");
     fwrite($myFile, $out);
     fclose($myFile);


  }
```

I've tried removing whitespaces and looking for escape characters. But as long as $date is appended to the filename, I get the error:

> fopen(misc/message_2018-02-0210:47:41): failed to open stream: Invalid
>   argument in C:\MAMP\htdocs\A2\report.php on line 76

I can get it to work if I don't put the timestamp on it. Any suggestions?

Comment: : are illegal characters for filenames

Comment: you cant use `:` as part of a filename. Change the date to `$date = $date->format('YmdHis);`